# An algebraic curve $C$ as a cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ramification

Could someone explain what it means for an algebraic curve $C$ to be a cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, ramified over $n$ points?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you're using (classical or modern). In the modern sense, it means that you have a curve $C$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (perhaps it was originally over some subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, but we just base change up to $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$) and a surjective map $\varphi:C\to\mathbb{P}^1$.

What it means for a point $x\in C$ to be *ramified* relative to this morphism is that the sheaf $\Omega^1_{C/\mathbb{P}^1}$ has non-zero stalk there. Or said differently (although equivalently, since I'm assuming $C/\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is smooth) that if $y=\varphi(x)$, and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1,y}\to\mathcal{O}_{C,x}$ is the natural map, that a uniformizer $\pi$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1,y}$ doesn't map to a uniformizer $\mathcal{O}_{C,X}$.

There is an easy way to understand the **images** of the points of ramification. If $[K(C):k(t)]=n$ (where $K(C)$ is the function field of $C$, and $k(t)$ the function field of $\mathbb{P}^1$) a point $y\in\mathbb{P}^1$ is the image of a point of ramification if the fiber contains less than $n$ points.

Intuitively, ramification means that $C\to\mathbb{P}^1$ is generally $n$-to-$1$, with $n$ "sheets", and the points of ramification are where these sheets come together. This can be made entirely formal if you further base change to $\mathbb{C}$, and look at the analytification of the curves. Then this becomes a finite map of Riemann surfaces (real surfaces, if that makes you happier), which is generically a covering map, except at the points of ramification!

Let me know if I can further clarify!

(PS: [Here's](https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2014/04/06/unramified-morphisms/) a shameless plug for a post on my blog talking about unramified morphisms. Check it out :) )

Comment: Is there a simpler formulation? We have not studied sheaves. It is such a simple statement, so I think there should be a very simple explanation. Am I mistaken? Your intuitive formulation resonates with me the most.

Comment: @glebovg It's hard to see without knowing what material you have/haven't covered. Can you explain more the context in which you were discussing this?

Comment: I am trying to understand Belyi's theorem.

Comment: @glebovg So the above definition(s) are the rigorous ones. I'm not sure what more you are looking for. I can give you more intuition, but the above definitions I gave you are the least technical ones. The only others involve looking at fibers, or saying that the diagonal map is an open embedding. Do either of those sound more appealing to you?

Comment: Not really. Thank you. Could you explain what it means for an algebraic curve to cover $\mathbb{P}^1$? An intuitive explanation would suffice.

Comment: @glebovg It literally just means (in what I believe is Shafarevich's parlance) a surjective map $C\to\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: Honestly? It seems rather superfluous and it bewilders the reader. Why not simply say that there is a surjection $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$? It baffles me.

Comment: @glebovg I mean, not really. A huge part of algebraic geometry is to think geometrically about algebraic objects. The objects $C$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$ are algebraic, and so is a surjection $C\to\mathbb{P}^1$. But, in our mind we're supposed to think about this as something "like a covering map" from topology (like I said above, it is except for some few trouble points [the ramification points]). There is a lot of this suggestive terminology that makes no literal sense, but indicates how one is supposed to think about the notion intuitively/geometrically.

Comment: Ok. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: @glebovg No problem. Hope it helped. :)